# Continue code execution on workbook after opening and writing to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

This code works and is called in the Print code. I can't figure how to then Save and Close this workbook.

The Inventory workbook Saves and Closes itself with `Worksheet_Change` code, but this workbook sticks at the last direction given before opening the Inventory file.

If there is no solution, I will use a button to Save and Close, which works but I know will cause files to be left open and confuse users.

I tried several ideas, such as `Exit Sub` and adding a separate macro that, in order, calls `CopyAndPasteToTracking` then `SaveAndClose`.  I think that the `End Sub` is being ignored because I can get no other code to execute after the last line before `End Sub` (except for using button to run another macro).

```vb
Sub CopyPasteToTracking()

Sheets("Export Table").Select
Range("$A$1:$K$" & Range("M1")).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sales Record").Select
Range("$A$10").Select

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
  "C:\Users\Michelle\Documents\Maple Inventory System\YYYY\YYYY SYRUP MANAGEMENT\test 
YYYY SYRUP INVENTORY TRACKING.xlsm"
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=5
Sheets("Sales").Select
Range("$B$" & (1 + Range("Y1"))).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
  xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

I also tried adding `ThisWorkbook.Save` and `ThisWorkbook.Close` after the command in Print procedure to call the macro and it didn't do either action.

Comment: Try to [avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and [refer to each sheet](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/) instead of using the active sheet

Comment: Thank you, but I do not believe that's the problem because I got the same behavior when I ended that part of the code at "copy".  I added the rest so that users would back on the sheet they started on.

Comment: If you just stop using things like `Select`, `ActiveWindow`, `Selection`, `Copy`, `Paste` and unqualified ranges and instead look into other options, the sheet wouldn't have to change in the first place, and it would be much faster.

Comment: Thank you, Brax.  If I remove the second part of the code to (go to the other workbook and paste) and instead close this workbook, it closes the workbook.  If I rewrite it, I get the same behavior, and the users action will meanwhile getting the printed pages in hand, so I decided to stick with language that someone would be more likely to understand, even though I doubt it will be seen again.

Comment: before you open the other workbook assign the activeworkbook to a variable (ex. mywb) then at the end after the paste use `mywb.close 1`

Comment: Thank you, k1dr0ck, but then the rest of the code did not run.   I have ended up with the most forceful approach of using application.quit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to force it to close, which works fine and won't hurt office users who might have other workbooks open.  Reason for this approach is that no user has ever posted their sales per the quick and easy instructions, so I have had to do it each year prior to files turnover for the new year.  This solves that issue.

Sub CopyPasteToTracking()

```
Sheets("Export Table").Select
Range("$A$1:$K$" & Range("M1")).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sales Record").Select
Range("$A$9").Select

Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\Michelle\Documents\Maple Inventory System\YYYY\YYYY SYRUP MANAGEMENT\test YYYY SYRUP INVENTORY TRACKING.xlsm"
ActiveWindow.ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=5
Sheets("Sales").Select
Range("$B$" & (1 + Range("Y1"))).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
For Each w In Application.Workbooks
    w.Save
    Next w
    Application.Quit
```

End Sub